# How to store image thumbnail on AWS s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a large number of images to store on S3 so what is the best approach to serving different size image for different screen size.

Do I need to resize **on-fly** or keep the different size of the same image in s3?
I search and found that

> Storage is cheap, compute is expensive.

So I decide to store multiple sizes of the image but still confuse which approach is best in the case of heavy traffic.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/1544/405).  Either this question or the one on DevOps should be deleted.

Comment: okay @Michael-sqlbot tanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to use a service that can resize on demand. See:

- [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/)
- [Imgix](http://imgix.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If it requires to have multiple image sizes, its cost effective and efficient to resize and store the different versions of the image in s3.

Generally having two sizes (full size & thumbnail) is more common in applications.

To generate different sizes of a particular image, you can use Lambda with s3 events and there are example [templates](https://github.com/trinketapp/aws-lambda-create-thumbnail) already available.

Comment: FYI S3 Reduced Redundancy Storage is now more expensive than S3 Standard. It used to be cheaper, but is no longer. You should use Standard or Standard - Infrequent Access depending on access patterns.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for pointing it out. I was surprised that no info available in aws why they are doing so. Later found the following article https://mysteriouscode.io/blog/aws-s3-storage-classes-pricing-is-not-what-you-think/ where it says AWS is going to discontinue reduced redundancy storage. I have modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation to serve multiple image sizes at high traffic, in which resulting me to store all image sizes in S3 only by demand. The foundation of resizing on-demand is as this [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/).

Although the images store in the S3, they are actually served by AWS CloudFront. Having CloudFront fronting the request, I think, will give economic benefits and reliability during high traffic timeframe.

Answer (score 1):

As compared to storing the images in S3 is **Cost Effective** compared to other storage options.

> Also the S3 is available at the *Global Level* so you don't need to
>   worry about your client and users geographically.

You can add a `CDN` for your images as well if you want to reduce the `latency`.

> For making the thumbnails of the images, I think the best solution
>   would be to use the Lambda service of AWS.

Lambda will generate the thumbnails of the images once your image in uploaded in S3. And you don't need to code in your application to do this process.

> So doing this your application load is reduced and images, thumbnails
>   are present globally and presented to end user with less latency.

Hope this helps.